# Witnesses in the Henkin construction and the canonical model

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

See the images below, from *Model theory: An Introduction, by David Marker*: In the proof of Lemma 2.1.7 the canonical model is defined using equivalence classes of constant symbols of $\mathcal{L}$, where the relation $\sim$ is defined by $c\sim d$ iff $T\vDash (c=d)$.

I am trying to understand why on page 36, the witness property is actually needed to demonstrate that $f^{\mathcal{M}}$ is well defined (and similarly a paragraph below regarding terms).

Focusing on functions, I wonder why he does not define $f^{\mathcal{M}}(c_{1}^{*},\ldots,c_{n}^{*})=(f(c_{1},\ldots,c_{n}))^{*}$, as it is clear this would be well definied because if $(c_{1}=d_{1}),\ldots,(c_{n}=d_{n})\in T$ then $(f(c_{1},\ldots,c_{n})=f(d_{1},\ldots,d_{n}))\in T$. (A similar argument can be made for the paragraph below regarding terms)

I have two questions:

1. **Am I missing something? I.e. is the witness property really needed?**
2. **If instead of using the constants symbols of $\mathcal{L}$ to define the canonical model we use the variable-free terms of $\mathcal{L}$ (the relation $\sim$ being defined the same as above, but for variable-free terms), is there any advantage? In *An Introduction to mathematical Logic, by R. Hodel*, the canonical model is defined this way.**

[image: page 35]
[image: page 36]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For question 1: $f(c_1,\dots,c_n)$ is not a constant symbol, so $(f(c_1,\dots,c_n))^*$ is meaningless.

As you suggest in question 2, you could instead define an equivalence relation on the set of all terms with no free variables and define the elements of the model to be equivalence classes of terms. Then you would not need to use the witnessing property to define the interpretations of the function symbols: $f(t_1^*,\dots,t_n^*) = (f(t_1,\dots,t_n))^*$ works just fine.

Is there any other advantage? Not really: the point is that the witnessing property ensures that every equivalence class of terms contains a constant symbol. Indeed, the model built on constants is isomorphic to the model built on terms. It's really a matter of taste whether you find it conceptually simpler to work with constants or arbitrary terms.

Comment: indeed, that escaped me )

Comment: Oh my, of course! It is not a constant, it is a term. Now I get it. What I wrote, more generally for variable-free terms in place of the constants, would be well defined without needeing witnesses if the canonical model had been defined using the variable-free terms of $\mathcal{L}$. And perhaps that's the advantage over defining the canonical model using the constants of $\mathcal{L}$. Thank you!

Comment: @John I added a bit to my answer to address your second question.

Comment: To understand your comment on both structures being isomorphic, we send $c^{*}$ to itself and a more general equivalence class of a ariable-free term $(f(t_{1},\ldots,t_{n}))^{*}$ to the unique $d^{*}$ such that $(f(t_{1},\ldots,t_{n})=d)\in T$. Am I correct?

Comment: @John Yes, correct. It's a good exercise to write out a careful proof that the map you defined is well-defined and an isomorphism.

Comment: I certainly will do that! Thank you.

Comment: After working out the exercise, it seems to me that we could simply define the equivalence relation on the set of terms, not just the variable-free terms, since any assigment $\phi$ from the variables into the domain sends each variable-free term $t$ to its equivalence class (that is, $\phi(t)=t^{*}$). I guess Hodel's reason for working with variable-free terms instead of just terms is to simplify some proofs.

Comment: @John Your proposal is to define an equivalence relation on all terms (even those with free variables) and take the domain of the model to be the set of equivalence classes of terms? I don't think this will work. For example, $x$ is a term with free variable $x$. Suppose our theory $T$ contains $\forall x\, P(x)\lor Q(x)$ but does not entail $P(x)$ or $Q(x)$. Then your model will not satisfy $P(x^*)$ or $Q(x^*)$, so it won't satisfy $T$. The point is that complete theories entail lots of things about terms with no free variables, but they entail much less about terms with free variables.

Comment: Yes, I certainly see your point. Enderton on p.137 of the 4th edition of A Mathematical Introduction to Logic uses the set of all terms of the language. I need to read it more carefully to see what he is doing. He defines de equivalence relation on p.140. The theory he works with is consistent and complete. Then it works. I think that is the key. Otherwise it fails as you pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to perform this construction. As the author states :

> The main idea of the construction is that we will add enough constants to the
> language so that every element of our model will be named by a constant symbol

This is why, for every $c_{1},\ldots,c_{n}$, the author needs to introduce a new constant $d$ satisfying $T \vdash f(c_{1},\ldots,c_{n}) = d$, for otherwise he'd miss that constant later on.