# Understanding the use of the Axiom of Choice in David Marker's proof of Compactness

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

I am trying to understand the use of the Axiom of Choice in the proof of Lemma 2.1.8 (page 37 below) in David Marker's *Model Theory: An Introduction*

Pages 35 and 36 can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4467686/witnesses-in-the-henkin-construction-and-the-canonical-model). Lemma 2.1.8 is part of a series of lemmas that begin on page 35 culminating in the proof of Theorem 2.1.11 (page 38). I identify two fundamental uses of Choice in the proof of this theorem:

One clear in Corollary 2.1.10 (page 38), although Zorn's Lemma can be avoided by using the Ultrafilter theorem. Then two apparent in the proof of Lemma 2.1.8. The first in choosing the model $\mathcal{M}$ satisfying $\Delta_0$, and the second in the assignment of constant symbols to elements in the domain $M$ of $\mathcal{M}$. It is these last apparent uses of Choice that I am trying to understand:

**Is it full Choice being used here? Can it be avoided?**

I though that the strength of Choice needed to prove Theorem 2.1.11 (Compactness Theorem) is only that of the ultrafilter theorem, which is used in Corollary 2.1.10.

Thank you in advance.

Note that in line 3, p.38 below there appears to be a typo. Where $\phi$ appears it should be $\phi_i$.

[image: page 37]
[image: page 38]

Comment: Thank you, I did before I asked the question. I also consulted Jech's books, which is where I learned that the Compactness Theorem is ZF equivalent to the ultrafilter theorem, and thus my question regarding Marker's apparent additional use of Choice in the proof of Lemma 2.1.8.

Comment: There are only finitely many $c_{\phi_i}$'s so no Choice is needed.

Comment: @EricWofsey I edited the question, as I noticed and additional apparent use of Choice when choosing $\mathcal{M}$ satisfying $\Delta_0$. Regarding your comment, for each constant we are choosing an element $a_i$ from the domain $M$ to assign to the constant. Yes, there are finitely many constants, but there could be infinitely many $a_i$ such that $\mathcal{M}\vDash\phi(a_i)$, no?

Comment: @EricWofsey Oh, I see what you mean. The collection of sets (each of which may be infinite) to choose from is finite. Yes, no choice needed. Thank you.

Comment: And an analogous argument shows the other apparent use of Choice is really not.

Comment: Compactness of FOL is known to be equivalent to the Boolean prime ideal theorem/ultrafilter lemma. Marker uses axiom of choice freely because he does not really care (at least in this part of the book) about non-ZFC model theory.