# Witnessing expansion of a first-order language and the use of the Axiom of Choice to expand any structure in the language

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

Understanding the use of the Axiom of Choice in the constructions mentioned in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4472616/understanding-the-use-of-the-axiom-of-choice-in-david-markers-proof-of-compactn) question prompted the following, which I will state as a Lemma:

Lemma: *Let $\mathcal{M}$ be any $\mathcal{L}$-structure of a first-order language $\mathcal{L}$, and let $\mathcal{L}^{*}$ be its witnessing expansion (see Lemma 2.1.8 page 38 in the linked question for details - the witnessing constants are denoted by $c_{\phi}$) then there is an assignment of the constant symbols of $\mathcal{L}^{*}$ to elements in the domain of $\mathcal{M}$ so that the expansion of $\mathcal{M}$ to $\mathcal{L}^{*}$ satisfies all of the $L^{*}$-sentences:
$$(\exists v\,\phi(v))\Rightarrow \phi(c_{\phi}).$$*

Proof: We accomplish this by assigning elements in the domain of $\mathcal{M}$ to the constants added at each step in the construction of $\mathcal{L}_{i}$ (again, see Lemma 2.1.8 for details). For example, the first step
$$\mathcal{L}_{1}=\mathcal{L}\cup\{c_{\phi}:\phi(v)\;\mbox{an $\mathcal{L}$-formula}\}.$$
Let $C_{1}$ denote the set of new constants above (added to $\mathcal{L}$). Then if $c_{\phi}\in C_{1}$ the sentence $\exists v\,\phi(v)$ makes sense in $\mathcal{M}$.

1. If $\mathcal{M}\vDash \exists v\,\phi(v)$, choose some $a$ in the domain of $\mathcal{M}$ such that $\mathcal{M}\vDash\phi(a)$ and assign $c_{\phi}$ the element $a$, i.e. $c_{\phi}^{\mathcal{M}}=a$.
2. If $\mathcal{M}\vDash \neg\exists v\,\phi(v)$, assign $c_{\phi}$ any element arbitrarily.

The process carries on to constants in subsequent sets $C_{2}, C_{3},$ etc.

**Two questions:**

**First, the set of constants $c_{\phi}$ in $C_{1}$ (and subsequent steps) may be infinite and thus Choice appears to be needed to obtain the $a$'s in (1). Is this use of Choice avoidable?**

**Second, the Lemma above seems to have echoes of Lindenbaum's theorem, which is ZF equivalent to the ultrafilter theorem. But the Lemma appears weaker, as countable Choice is all it seems to require. Is this correct?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of choice is indeed unavoidable.

One form of the axiom of choice states that for all surjective $f : A \to B$, where $B$ is nonempty, there is some $g : B \to A$ such that $f \circ g = 1_B$. We will prove this form of the axiom of choice from your Lemma.

Consider a surjective function $f : A \to B$.

Let us consider a two-sorted theory, one sort $\mathscr{A}$ with Latin letter variables, the other sort $\mathscr{B}$ with Greek letter variables. Since we have a finite number of sorts, we can rephrase our results to fit into one-sorted logic, if this is what your book requires.

Our vocabulary with consist of a single function symbol $\mathscr{f} : \mathscr{A} \to \mathscr{B}$ together with, for each $b \in B$, a constant symbol $q_b \in \mathscr{B}$. This vocabulary we shall call $\mathscr{L}$.

Let $M$ be the obvious structure for this language; $\mathscr{A}$ corresponds with $A$, $\mathscr{B}$ with $B$, $\mathscr{f}$ with $f$, and each $q_b$ with $b$. Consider some extension of the structure on $M$ to an $\mathscr{L}^*$ structure.

For all $b \in B$, define $\phi_b(a) :\equiv \mathscr{f}(a) = q_b$. Now for all $b \in B$, we have $M \vDash \exists a (\phi_b(a))$, since $f$ is surjective. Therefore, for all $b \in B$, we have $M \vDash \phi_b(c_{\phi_b})$. In particular, we have $f((c_{\phi_b})_M) = b$.

Define $g : B \to A$ by $g(b) = (c_{\phi_b})_M$. Then we see that for all $b \in B$, we have $f(g(b)) = b$. So $f \circ g = 1_B$.

So we have proved the axiom of choice.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, and I thought countable Choice would do. Wrong! Full Choice is required to prove the Lemma. I did not think of trying to prove full Choice, I was trying to prove Lindenbaum's Theorem, as the more I thought about it the more I realized I had it backwards and the lemma was the stronger of the two.

Comment: The whole idea for the Lemma in my question comes from what Marker does to prove that $T_{1}$ is finitely satisfiable in Lemma 2.1.8. He extends the structure $\mathcal{M}$ so that it satisfies the $\mathcal{L}_{1}$-sentences of the type I describe in my Lemma for the finitely many witnessing constants mentioned in the finite set $\Delta_{0}$. All I did was to see that indeed, if you keep adding constants you can keep expanding $\mathcal{M}$, so that what he was doing generalizes to the entire witnessing expansion $\mathcal{L}^{*}$. But, paying a price with Choice :)

Comment: I have a question: Is it necessary to have the constants $q_{b}$ in $\mathscr{L}$? It seems that expressing the onto function $f$ as a single-sorted structure only requires a vocabulary $\mathscr{L}$ with one relation symbol $f$ because the domain and range of $f$ are definable by $\exists x\, \mathscr{f}xy$ and $\exists y\, \mathscr{f}xy$. Can't the $\phi_{b}(a)$ you define not be define as $\phi_{y}(x):=\mathscr{f}xy$? (as I am thinking of the function $f$ as a relation, $\mathscr{f}xy$ intuitively means $(x,y)\in f$, i.e. $f(x)=y$).

Comment: @John There is no such thing as $\phi_y(x) := \mathscr{f} x y$ because $y$ is not a term in $\mathscr{L}$; it’s an element of $B$. We need some way of taking elements of $B$ and getting terms of sort $\mathscr{B}$.

Comment: Thank you. In my argument I was thinking in a single-sorted language and structure. $\mathscr{L}$ consist just of a 2-ary relation symbol $F$ (variable set $\{x,y,z,\ldots\}$. Thus the appropriate $L$-structure $\mathcal{M}$ expressing that $f$ is an onto funtion $f:A\rightarrow B$ has   domain $A\cup B$ and $F^{\mathcal{M}}:=f$. Am I mistaken? Then, $x, y$ are terms, and $\mathscr{f}xy$ is a valid $L$-formula, is it not? How would one proceed from this $\mathcal{M}$, with your argument to prove AC from the Lemma?

Comment: @John Again, not every element of a model can be denoted by a term. By analogy, consider a model of Peano arithmetic; the only elements of the model which are denoted by terms are the standard numbers. To make my approach work for a single-sorted logic, our vocabulary would have a single binary relation symbol $\mathcal{f}$ together with, for each $b \in B$, a symbol $q_b$. The model would then be $A \cup B$ with relation $f$ and symbols $(q_b)^\mathcal{M} = b$.

Comment: Oh, yes. I see it now thanks to your example using PA. Thank you for your patience, it is clear I still have not fully internalized the distinction between syntax and meaning.